# Google Cloud VM instance can't start and cannot be moved because of terminated state

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I wanted to resize RAM and CPU of my machine, so I stopped the VM instance and when I tried to start it I got an error:

> The zone 'projects/freesarkarijobalerts/zones/asia-south1-a' does not
> have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a
> different zone, or try again later.`

Here you can see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koyXH.png).

I've tried to start VM instance today, but result was the same and I got an error message again:

> The zone 'projects/freesarkarijobalerts/zones/asia-south1-a' does not
> have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a
> different zone, or try again later.`

Then I tried to move my instance to different region, but I got an error message:

```
sarkarijobalerts123@cloudshell:~ (freesarkarijobalerts)$ gcloud compute instances move wordpress-2-vm --zone=asia-south1-a --destination-zone=asia-south1-b
Moving gce instance wordpress-2-vm...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instance cannot be moved while in state: TERMINATED
```

My website is DOWN for a couple of days, please help me.

Comment: Hi! Please contact the Google Cloud Suppport team as from there we will be able to help you further https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Answer (score 0):

The standard procedure is to create a snapshot out of the stopped VM instance [1] and then create a new one in another zone [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restore_a_snapshot_of_a_persistent_disk_to_a_new_disk

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at **the cause of this issue**:

1. When you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory.
2. When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

   ```
   Error: The zone 'projects/freesarkarijobalerts/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
   ```

   more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

   > If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
   > or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
   > resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
   > request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
   > and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.
3. Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve your issue**:

1. Move your instance to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) by following [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).
2. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future:

> Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
> zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
> additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
> your workloads when you need them. After you create a reservation, you
> begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
> available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
> is deleted.